# What is a good Network/Windows Server monitoring solution (Ideally web based)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-monitoring

I'm looking for something that is similar to Nagios for network and server monitoring, however, I do not have direct *Public* IP connection, or domain connection to the sites that require monitoring.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What options DO you have for communicating with these devices if you don't have IP connectivity?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Public IP communication. I can connect to these devices via LogMeIn for instance, but I couldn't connect using MSTSC from a Windows PC.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.serverdensity.com/

a web based tool, you can install a copy on your own server, then install agents on machines needed to be monitored.

Answer (score 0):

From your wording I gather you want to be able to monitor the systems remotely. Is there any reason you can't install Nagios (or similar) locally on those systems? You can use DynDNS or similar to provide a consistent means of accessing the web interface.

Comment: I guess not, but I think installing Nagios to only monitor one or two servers per site, would probably be overkill? 
I'm trying to find an easier solution :-)

Comment: You can then use NSCA to push all the checks to a central Nagios for ease of monitoring (plus having a way to notice if nagios dies). This doesn't require that the central can talk to the ends, they just have to be able to talk back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/), if you grow to be bigger it fits in well with nagios. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) may also be of some assistance depending on what exactly you are trying to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

if you want something web based you should look at something hosted like [HP Critical Watch Remote Monitoring](http://h20219.www2.hp.com/services/us/en/continuity-availability/missioncritical-criticalwatch.html) or [infrawatch](http://www.inteqnet.com/itsm-software.html)